# Cómo evitamos la condición de carrera en scala?

Tags: programación-funcional, scala

Tengo entendido que la condición de carrera sucede cuando dos hilos acceden a un mismo estado, modificándolo cada uno por su parte. Luego de esto, el valor resultante va a ser diferente al esperado e incluso puede ser distinto en cada ejecución.
Aquí un ejemplo de una sección crítica (en Java):

```
public class Counter {

     protected long count = 0;

     public void add(long value){
         this.count = this.count + value;
     }
  }
```

Si Pedro y Ana ejecutan en un hilo diferente la función add() uno le agrega 5 y el otro le agrega 2. 
El resultado será  el valor escrito por el último hilo. Por ende si el hilo de Pedro se ejecuta de último, el valor será 5. Pero si se ejecuta de último el hilo de Ana, el valor será 2. Lo que realmente debió suceder, es que se agregaran los dos valores y el resultado final fuera 7.

En Scala aplicando "programación funcional" nos hablan que evitemos los estados compartidos y que debemos usar estructuras inmutables como los ADT.  Pero para entender esta solución necesito un ejemplo donde se simule esta concurrencia, puede ser el de una consignación en una cuenta de ahorros. Digamos que Luis y Maria, consignan al mismo tiempo $10 y $5 respectivamente en la misma cuenta. Supongamos que la información de la cuenta reposa en una base de datos, además estamos trabajando con futuros en Scala y adicional a eso al realizar una consignación el sistema te entrega inmediatamente el saldo actual. ¿Cómo juega la inmutabilidad y los estados no compartidos para que al usuario se le muestre la información correcta bajo este escenario?

Aquí el código scala que ejemplifica la condición de carrera:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

trait Cuenta
case class CuentaAhorros(numero:String, cantidad:BigDecimal, idUser:String) extends Cuenta

trait OperacionesCuenta {

  def buscarCuenta(numeroCuenta:String):Future[CuentaAhorros] = Future{
    // supongamos que fuimos a bd y nos trajo la cuenta
    CuentaAhorros("021-123-456-11", 20, "1067905803")
  }

  def consignar(cuentaAhorros: CuentaAhorros, valor:BigDecimal):Future[Cuenta] = Future{
    cuentaAhorros.copy(cantidad = cuentaAhorros.cantidad + valor)
  }

  def transaccion(numeroCuenta:String, valor:BigDecimal): Future[Cuenta] =
    for {
      cuentaObjetivo <- buscarCuenta(numeroCuenta)
      cuentaActualizada <- consignar(cuentaObjetivo, valor)
    }yield cuentaActualizada
}

object Operaciones extends App with OperacionesCuenta{
  val transaccion1: Future[Cuenta] =  transaccion("021-123-456-11", 20)
  val transaccion2: Future[Cuenta] =  transaccion("021-123-456-11", 40)

  transaccion1 onComplete {
    case Success(cuenta) => println("Cuenta en la trasacción 1 = " + cuenta)
    case Failure(e) => println("A ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage)
  }

  transaccion2 onComplete {
    case Success(cuenta) => println("Cuenta en la trasacción 2 = " + cuenta)
    case Failure(e) => println("A ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage)
  }

  Thread.sleep(2000)

}
```

El resultado de la ejecución fué el siguiente:

Cuenta en la trasacción 1:  CuentaAhorros(021-123-456-11,40,1067905803)

Cuenta en la trasacción 2 : CuentaAhorros(021-123-456-11,60,1067905803)

Comment: Aquí el código scala que ejemplifica la condición de carrera:

Comment: La pregunta es muy interesante, pero estos temas de programación concurrente no son sencillos de explicar. Eso sí, advertirte que tu ejemplo en scala no hay condición de carrera ya que cada proceso opera con objetos `CuentaAhorros` independientes. Los *futuros* los uso más para obtener datos donde no se producen *cambios de estado*. Para cambios de estado en concurrencia resulta más adecuado el modelo actor que ofrece la librería akka. De todos modos, déjame unos días para pensar en una respuesta.

Comment: Hola @ChemaCortes muchas gracias por tu comentario. Quiero darme a entender mejor. En el ejemplo descrito anteriormente, si se está dando una condición de carrera porque dos hilos al mismo tiempo accedieron a la bd y se trajeron la misma cuenta "021-123-456-11", ya en memoria, los dos hicieron una consignación y cada quién por su lado hizo el update en la  tabla de la bd. El resultado esperado era que en la cuenta hubiera $80, pero vemos en la ejecución del programa que la última actualización guardó $60, lo cual, representa que se perdieron $20.

Comment: @ChemaCortes con respecto al **modelo de actores con akka**, muchas personas que conocen del tema, me han dicho que es una de las mejores opciones para manejar la concurrencia. Y como dices el tema es muy interesante para echarle una estudiada.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres ejemplificar. Pero en este código, tal cuál está, cada hilo usa su propia instancia de `CuentaAhorros`, por lo que no están compitiendo por los mismos recursos, por lo que no hay condición de carrera. Emular las transacciones de una base de datos con futuros requeriría incorporarles *efectos colaterales*, algo que no es nada recomendable ya que los futuros, al igual que `lazy vals`, sólo se ejecutan una vez. Hay que pensar mejor cómo encadenar dos transacciones con futuros de modo que se pueda producir una condición de carrera (o sea, que llegue antes una u otra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los *futuros* parecen un modo simple de lanzar hilos, pero su ejecución termina cuando se obtiene el resultado (*promesa*). A partir de entonces usará siempre el valor calculado, por lo que cualquier *efecto colateral* que haga ya no se volverá a repetir.

Por ejemplo:

```
val trans = Future {
    println("Hola")
    1
}

for {
    i <- 1 to 10
    x <- trans
} println(x)
```

El futuro `trans` sólo imprime un único `"Hola"`, aunque devuelve el valor `1` tantas veces como se requiere.

No existe una única forma de diseñar una aplicación para su ejecución  concurrente y sería un tema demasiado amplio para exponer aquí. Cada aplicación concurrente requiere una solución diferente. Probablemente, este problema se solucione mejor con el *modelo actor* (librería `akka`).

En nuestro caso, no es posible emular una transacción bancaria con futuros. Necesitamos un objeto que haga de Banco que opere con nuestras cuentas. En producción, esta labor sería realizada por una base de datos, un servicio web u otra entidad. En el ejemplo que pongo se emula con el objeto `Banco` que controla los cambios de estado de las cuentas. Pongo el código y luego lo explico:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, Await }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure }
import scala.util.Random

trait Cuenta
case class CuentaAhorros(numero: String, idUser: String, saldo: BigDecimal) extends Cuenta

case object RaceConditionException extends Exception

object Banco {

  var cuentaPrincipal = CuentaAhorros("021-123-456-11", "1067905803", 20)

  def saldoActual = cuentaPrincipal.saldo

  def buscarCuenta(numeroCuenta: String): Future[CuentaAhorros] = Future {
    cuentaPrincipal
  }

  def consignar(cuenta: CuentaAhorros, nuevoSaldo: BigDecimal): Future[CuentaAhorros] = Future {

    // Tiempo de espera aleatorio
    Thread.sleep(10 * Random.nextInt(20))

    // Si el saldo ha cambiado, rechazamos la operación
    if (cuenta.saldo != saldoActual)
      throw RaceConditionException
    else
      cuentaPrincipal = cuentaPrincipal.copy(saldo = nuevoSaldo)

    cuentaPrincipal
  }

}

object MyApp extends App {

  def transaccion(numCuenta: String, incSaldo: BigDecimal): Unit = {

    val trans = for {
      cuenta <- Banco.buscarCuenta("021-123-456-11")
      nuevaCuenta <- Banco.consignar(cuenta, cuenta.saldo + incSaldo)
    } yield nuevaCuenta

    // Si falla la transacción, repetimos la operación
    trans.failed foreach {
      case RaceConditionException =>
        println(f"No he podido terminar la transacción ($numCuenta,$incSaldo%8.2f). Reiniciando...")
        transaccion(numCuenta, incSaldo)
    }

  }

  for {
    s <- 20 to 100 by 20
  } transaccion("021-123-456-11", s)

  Thread.sleep(1000)

  println(s"Saldo final: ${Banco.saldoActual}")

}
```

He usado una técnica llamada [CAS (check and swap)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparar_e_intercambiar). Cuando el objeto `Banco` tiene que consolidar el saldo, chequea antes que el saldo con el que ha estado trabajado el proceso es idéntico al actual. En caso contrario rechaza la operación porque supone que otro proceso había modificado el saldo. El proceso que ve rechazada su operación, se reinicia y vuelve a empezar.

Podemos asegurar que este diseño para la transacción será una *"operación atómica"* (al menos uno de los procesos acabará en un número fijo de pasos). Si ejecutamos el programa varias veces, veremos que algunos procesos aleatoramiente tendrán que reiniciar su proceso, pero al final todos ellos serán ejecutados y el saldo final siempre será el mismo. Seguramente no sea el modo más óptimizado de resolver este problema.

Espero que haya servido para responder a tu pregunta.